# If post submit statement not getting past for each loop

Tags: php, mysql, variables, foreach, conditional-statements

Thanks in advance, here is what is going on:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$var = $_GET['var'];

foreach((array)$_POST['content'] as $area => $contents)
    {

        $result = 'UPDATE $table SET '.$area.' = "'.mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($contents)).'" WHERE var = "'.$_GET['var'].'";';
        mysql_query ($result);
    }


$query = 'UPDATE $table SET '.
            'title = "'.mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["title"])).'", '.
            'template = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["templateid"]).'", '.
            'description = "'.mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["description"])).'", '.
            'keywords = "'.mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["keywords"])).'" '.
            ' WHERE var = "'.$_GET['var'].'";';

mysql_query ($query);// or die(mysql_error());

}
```

I am unable to get the if statement to go beyond the for each loop.  It will not update the database with the $query mysql statement.  It simple updates the table for everything inside the for each loop and then exists.  Do I need to do an If while or else if?  And I tried looking up php conditional statements, is there such a thing as and statements?  Such as: If post submit do this AND this?  That is essentially what I am trying to do, If post submit, do for each loop AND do $query.

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, is `$_POST['content']` defined at all? In cases like this you may want to start debugging with `print_r($_POST)` to see all values that you get.

What you probably intended to do is:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
```

---

*Edit:*
And you should **really** escape that `$_GET['var']` as well as the `$area` in the loop!!! Escape ALL user input, always!!!

Comment: I will add the escapes.  content[] is the name of text areas.  the for each loop runs perfectly and updates the table, however.  it never gets to the second query

Answer (score 0):

The table name wont be showing. Also add something to show the mysql error message to help debug:

```
$result = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.$area.' = "'.mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($contents)).'" WHERE var = "'.$_GET['var'].'";';
mysql_query ($result) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

try and add *ini_set('display_errors',1);* add the start of the script to ensure error ouput.
And use *var_dump(mysql_error());* to display the mysql error of the second query.

And a small suggestion.
do a switch on $area to ensure the valid fields are passed:

```
switch ($area) {
  case 'field1': $area='field1'; break;
  case 'field2': $area='field2'; break;
  default: echo 'No valid field'; continue; break;
}
```

good luck!